# Parallelization of tasks in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there an efficient way to run tasks in parallel in Snowflake? I am creating them through Python Connector.
The logic is as follows:
I have TASK 1 and TASK 2 dependent on TASK 1.
I want to be able to run this process (TASK 1 + TASK 2) n times, with a different id passed each time.
Both of these tasks call Stored Procedures that need that ID as an input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a task DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) to run child tasks in parallel and control dependencies before one or more descendent tasks runs:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro#dag-of-tasks